# How to check if the nullable integer/long variable is not null and has a value in C#?

Tags: c#

If I have Nullable Integer variable declared and I want to know whether the Variable is Null or has some value in it.

How do I check that? Is there a  function as similar to `string.IsNullOrEmpty()` for Integer and Long data type?

Comment: it has ``HasValue`` property like : ``long? number = null;`` and check if it contains null like : ``if(number.HasValue)``, it will return ``true`` if it is ``null``

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `HasValue` property of the `Nullable<T>`.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s.aspx

Alternatively, you can use `GetValueOrDefault` to return the contained value if the `Nullable` has a value or otherwise `default(T)`. For `Nullable<int>` and `Nullable<long>` it will be `0`, for `Nullable<string>` (or any reference type), it will be `null`.

You can also use `GetValueOrDefault(T)` to pass a value as a default to return if `HasValue` is `false`. For example, the following will return `10`:

```
int? nullableValue = null;
int intValue = nullableValue.GetValueOrDefault(10);
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/72cec0e0.aspx